# Regexp breaks Angular lazy load module from loading (Safari only)

Tags: angular, safari

I have the following line in an Angular lazy loaded module (originally not called 'evilRegex').
It doesn't get executed, only defined - and the RegExp and lazy module work just fine as intended in Chrome.

```
  const evilRegex = new RegExp(/(?<=<)([a-z0-9]+)(?=[ >])/g);
```

I am getting a `ChunkLoadError` is raised when the lazy module is loaded, but the URL returned in the error is valid and accessible if loaded directly.

I know that no code is executing because I see this alert box.

```
 loadChildren: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "pages_home" */ './rr2/page-designer/pages/pages.module')
                     .then(m => { return m.PagesModule; } ).catch(e => alert('***' + e))
```

In addition, putting `try / catch` around it does nothing so the error must be some kind of module load error. It only happens in Safari and only with this exact RegExp - so it's also not a caching issue.

I'm seeing this only on my iPhone so I can't view the console for any errors.

Does Safari not support negative lookbehind Regex? Is it because somehow `<=<` is tripping over the module parser?

More concerning is perhaps that since the actual error doesn't propagate all I would see in my log files is 'ChunkLoadError' which is indistinguishable from a connection issue.

Note: I am using Safari 14 Beta, but see the same in 13.5. If someone with a Mac could add this to a lazy module - just the definition - I'm hoping it would show some details in the console.

Comment: So it looks like 'lookbehind' in RegEx is not supported in Safari - but I still don't understand why this would not just fail at runtime. https://caniuse.com/#feat=js-regexp-lookbehind

Comment: Here's the error on [Mac Console](https://pasteboard.co/Ji0OTqF.png)

Comment: I just tested with [Browser Stack](https://live.browserstack.com/)

Comment: @BasheerKharoti thanks a lot :) crazy how that just breaks everything.

Comment: @BasheerKharoti I used to subscribe years ago but I’d go months and months without ever logging in.

Comment: I just tested with a free plan as it lets you test for at least a minute for each device.

Comment: Why don't you try this `new RegExp('(?<=<)([a-z0-9\]+)(?=[ >\])');`? Passing value as a string